Django test client redirects logged users to login page
I know this questions has already been asked, but none of the answers works for me.
Whenever I try to use the client login in Django tests, it basically gets ignored and I get a redirect to the login page. After a few test I noticed that it logs me in correctly, but kicks me out when I use it.
Here is a stripped down version of my code that still reproduces this.
from django.auth import get_user

class MapListViewTest(TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # Create a user
        cls.user = get_user_model().objects.create(username="testuser")
        cls.user.set_password("password")
        cls.user.save()

        # [...]

    def setUp(self):
        self.client.login(
            username=self.user.get_username(), password="password"
        )

    def test_map_list_view_renders(self):
        """Test that the MapListView renders successfully and includes a list of maps."""
        logger.info(get_user(self.client)) # <-- <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7377d5589540>
        
        self.client.login(
            username=self.user.get_username(), password="password"
        )
        logger.info(get_user(self.client)) # <-- <Profile: testuser>

        response = self.client.get(reverse("map_list"), follow=True)
        logger.info(get_user(self.client)) # <-- <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x7377d5589540>

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200) # <-- OK
        self.assertTemplateUsed(response, "map_list.html") # <-- lands on 'account/login.html'

(I put it twice here in the snippet, but it is only in the setUp in the real code)
I don't know if this is of any relevance, but the redirection changes the address from http://localhost/... to http://testserver/..., and I am working in a docker container.
Also, the user model inherits from AbstractUser and has no custom logic on login.
EDIT: I changed the password to be plaintext, even tried with force_login, I get the same behaviour.

In the self.client.login
self.client.login(
        username=self.user.get_username(), password=self.user.password
    )

Here self.user.password doesn't work because it's a hashed password, whereas the method expects a plain text password.
Try these
self.client.login(username=self.user.get_username(), password="password")

We replace the self.user.password with "password" to have the password in clear text.

Thanks, I changed the password to be plaintext, even tried with force_login(self.user) instead if the regular login, I still get the same behavior unfortunately

according to the error, Django is trying to send you to the right page after the connection, but there's a mismatch between the domain names used (localhost and testserver).
Try adding the following to the settings.py file
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['testserver', 'localhost']

This allows these two domains to be authorised in requests

No that does not fix it, that is not an issue with allowed hosts. For next comments add it as a response to this one, so it's easier to keep track of the whole conversation :)

try removing follow=True to see exactly where the initial redirect leads and why the login page is displayed.

I get <HttpResponseRedirect status_code=302, "text/html; charset=utf-8", url="http://localhost/account/login/?next=http%3A//testserver/maps/">, althouogh I am logged in
